# Diferenças e semelhanças entre “estar a fim” e “estar com vontade”

Tags: significado, uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Eu falo nativamente espanhol. Meus professores sempre traduziram as expressões espanholas que usam a palavra *ganas* (*tener ganas*, *estar con ganas*) com *vontade*, e essa é a palavra que eu costumo usar, mas tenho ouvido *estar a fim de (fazer alguma coisa)* com o mesmo significado, ou pelo menos com o que parece ser o mesmo significado.

Eu acho que as duas expressões não são totalmente equivalentes e também não podem usadas com a mesma gramática, mas **quais são as diferenças entre *estar a fim* e *estar com vontade*?** E quando é que são mesmo sinônimas? Finalmente, tem alguma outra expressão similar que seja usada habitualmente? Alguns exemplos seriam bem-vindos.

Comment: Você já consultou o Priberam? https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fim a fim de e ter vontade são a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Embora duas palavras ou expressões possam ter significados semelhantes, ou mesmo idênticos, **é sempre possível encontrarmos usos idiomáticos de uma ou de outra.**  Em tese, "ter vontade de" e "estar a fim de" são sinônimos. Contudo, existem situações em que uma é usada e a outra soa muito estranha. Exemplos:

- "Estou com vontade de vomitar." (não diríamos "estou a fim de vomitar")
- "Eu fiquei com vontade de chorar quando vi aquela cena." (idem)

Como podemos observar, "estar a fim de" não se presta muito a expressar o "sentimento de nossos órgãos internos", mas sim **a determinação a, ou a intenção de, fazer algo**.  Notem a diferença:

- "Estou com uma vontade enorme de ir ao banheiro." -- a vontade não vem do cérebro, mas sim de outra parte. E não se trata propriamente de vontade, mas da necessidade urgente de atualizar as funções fisiológicas de eliminação.
- "Estou muito a fim de ir ao banheiro." -- soa mais como uma determinação pessoal consequente à necessidade física ou não, enquanto "estou com muita vontade" tem mais a conotação de necessidade urgente.

Acrescento ainda que "estar a fim de + verbo" é algo informal, e que "estar a fim de + substantivo" é gíria.

- "Eu estou a fim daquela mulher."
- "Eu estou a fim de uma boa transa."
- "Estou muito a fim dela."

A pergunta pede também que sejam citadas expressões semelhantes. Embora seja considerado "off topic" oferecer listas aqui no PL, posso citar algumas:

- Estou querendo muito...
- Estou doido/louco para...
- Estou ávido por...
- Estou determinado a...
- Estou almejando...

Observe, no entanto, que cada uma delas tem o seu uso restrito a determinados contextos.  Dizer "estou ávido por ir ao banheiro" ou "estou almejando ir à praia" soa ridículo.

p.s.  Também temos a palavra "gana" (vontade, impulso, fome) em português, só que pouco se usa. Em pt-BR já ouvi em "tenho ganas de te matar, de te dar um soco na cara (coisas desse tipo).

p.s.2 -  Minha resposta refere-se ao uso das expressões em pt-BR.

Comment: Tem de explicar isso: "Estou com vontade de vomitar." (não diríamos "estou a fim de vomitar")"; vontade é mais fisiológica, causada por ânsia ou sensação; a fim de é mais racional, e nesse caso seria querer fazer isso por um motivo (pode soar levemente como se você tivesse afinidade por vomitar). Mesmo assim as pessoas usam as duas formas como se fossem a mesma coisa ignorando detalhes.

Comment: @AndréLyra   Não usei a palavra "racional" mas expliquei que: "soa como uma determinação pessoal"  ........ "a determinação a, ou a intenção de, fazer algo".   **"determinação pessoal" provém da razão**.

Comment: Acho que "estar a fim" também pode significar apenas "estar interessado".

Comment: @BrunoLopes   Sim, Bruno, concordo.  E "estar com vontade" também.   ("Estou com muita vontade de saber o que os dois estavam conversando."